# better way of applying a ratio to a coordinate

Tags: linear-algebra

I am given a point Q (5, 6) and its the midpoint between another coordinate R.  The coordinate of the midpoint T is (1, 4) and I am asked to work out R.

I can see that the steps on the x axis between 5 and 1 are - 4 and I can see that from 6 on the y axis to 4 is a drop of 2.

So I can work out R is (-3, 2).

Is there a more concise way of working this out and a way I can clearly show how I got here?

Comment: This is precisely the way I would do it, I doubt there is a more concise way of working this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the general formula for a point reflection: if $(a,b)$ and $(a',b')$ are symmetric w.r.t. $(\alpha,\beta)$, then
$$a'=2\alpha-a,\quad b'=2\beta-b.$$

This generalises to higher dimensions, of course.